# I have an ESlint error in my Vue.js project, why can't I fix it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

A few months ago I came across this error in my vue.js project
line numbers 22, 23 and 24 relate to lines 45, 46 and 47 in my code block at the bottom

```
{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/Demo User/Documents/vue/mynewwebsite/src/App.vue",
    "owner": "eslint",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected \",\"\n\n  22 |   }\n  23 | }\n> 24 |\n     | ^",
    "source": "eslint",
    "startLineNumber": 47,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 47,
    "endColumn": 1
}
```

Since then I have tried to find solutions on SO and google and I asked a friend.
I thought it was just a comma in the wrong place and tried adding and removing commas in appropriate places but that didn't help (edit:  I had missed a curly brace, duh)

Here is my code from the script tag in `App.vue`

```
25 <script>
26 import Modal from './components/Modal.vue';
27 export default {
28  name: 'App',
29  components: { Modal, },
30  data() {
31    return {
32      title: 'my new website',
33      header: 'Modal Header',
34      text: 'modal content',
35      showModal: false,
36      showModalTwo: false
37    }
38  },
39  methods: {
40    toggleModal() {
41      this.showModal = !this.showModal;
42    },
43    toggleModalTwo() {
44      this.showModalTwo = !this.showModalTwo;
45  }
46 }
47 </script>
```

Comment: You don't close your function `toggleModalTwo` with a `}`

Comment: How did I not see that. Thanks, that fixed the ESlint error. Still getting the npm run serve error though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a '}' in `toggleModalTwo`